# How to pass login page for Office365 portal with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, authentication, office365

I am trying to write *PowerShell* script which will retrieve some information from Office 365 portal page, specifically name and URL of some custom application. I was planning to use *Invoke-WebRequest* commandlet and parse the result, but the problem is that I cannot get past Office 365 authentication page. When I type:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://myapps.microsoft.com" -UseBasicParsing
```

I receive this result:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           :

                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <title>Sign in to your account</title>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                        <meta http-eq...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
                    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
                    X-Frame-Options: DENY
                     Link: <https://aadcdn.msftauth.net>; rel=prec...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Pragma, no-cache], [Strict-Transport-Security, max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains], [X-Content-Type-Options, nosniff], [X-Frame-Options, DENY]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 32302
```

If I run the command without *UseBasicParsing* parameter, a browser opens https://login.microsoftonline.com/cookiesdisabled page.
Is there any way to specify credentials for login so that *PowerShell* will pass the login window and reach page with Office 365 apps?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in order to access the Office 365 API you need to authenticate first and get an [authentication token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis#request-access-tokens-from-azure-ad). There are actually several steps that you need to do in order to use PowerShell to access the Office 365 API that is too broad for a SO answer, and I recommend going through the documentation: [Get started with Office 365 Management APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis) where it goes through all of the steps:

1. **Register your application in Azure AD.** To allow your application access to the Office 365 Management APIs, you need to register your application in Azure AD. This allows you to establish an identity for your application and specify the permission levels it needs to access the APIs.
2. **Get Office 365 tenant admin consent.** An Office 365 tenant admin must explicitly grant consent to allow your application to access their tenant data by means of the Office 365 Management APIs. The consent process is a browser-based experience that requires the tenant admin to sign in to the Azure AD consent UI and review the access permissions that your application is requesting, and then either grant or deny the request. After consent is granted, the UI redirects the user back to your application with an authorization code in the URL. Your application makes a service-to-service call to Azure AD to exchange this authorization code for an access token, which contains information about both the tenant admin and your application. The tenant ID must be extracted from the access token and stored for future use.
3. **Request access tokens from Azure AD.** Using your application's credentials as configured in Azure AD, your application requests additional access tokens for a consented tenant on an ongoing basis, without the need for further tenant admin interaction. These access tokens are called app-only tokens because they do not include information about the tenant admin.
4. **Call the Office 365 Management APIs.** The app-only access tokens are passed to the Office 365 Management APIs to authenticate and authorize your application.

Another tutorial is [Getting started with Microsoft Graph and PowerShell](https://www.lee-ford.co.uk/getting-started-with-microsoft-graph-with-powershell/)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I'm a bit confused about this topic, as this is a bit new for me. What is considered to be an app? I am not trying to access any particular application or create one, just to open portal.office.com page from powershell as I would from browser. If I undestood correctly, _Invoke-WebRequest_ is commandlet that should do the job, but clientID, applicationID and similar parameters are confusing me.

Comment: Basically, step 1 is that you need to authenticate in order to access anything in O365. You can authenticate either as an Active Directory user, which should be just for users, or as an "application" which is meant for non-users. If you are using PowerShell and automating it, the "best" way is to set up an "application". Don't get hung up on the name, it's just a fancy word for a generic non-user that needs access, this includes API's, Websites, automation, etc. Once the app is set up, you can create keys and tokens to give your script access.